# Anaconda navigator only showing one python version

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have installed Anaconda in order to set up different environments for python. I know that I can create different environments with different python versions with the shell, like so:

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.6
```

How would I be able to create a new environment with Python 3.6 using the Anaconda navigator. For some reason it only shows Python version 3.7

[image: Anaconda Navigator]

Comment: if you want other version you need to install them

Comment: Well, how do I install them? Secondly, do you mean install different python versions or different anaconda versions?

Comment: Why does it work with command line and not with the GUI?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue and was hoping there would be an answer here. I finally found the following which *directly* answers your question.  Thanks for asking!

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html

Specifically, do the following:

Installing a different version of Python.  Create the new environment:

To create the new environment for Python 3.6, in your terminal window or an Anaconda Prompt, run:

```
conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda
```

You need not go any further.  From this point forward, every time you create a new environment, you will see:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I know this answer has been accepted a while ago but, from Anaconda Navigator, clicking "Update index..." button on the default environment fixed it for me (without having to use conda command prompt)
[image]

Comment: that fixed it for me, anaconda navigator wasnt able to detect python 3.6, after update index my navigator updated to a newer version and now everything works.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to installing the metapackage

```
conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda
```

you must activate the environment (also in anaconda prompt)

```
conda activate py36
```

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda comes with one Python version upon first installation. Once you have created the first environment from the anaconda prompt/terminal, e.g. with `conda create -n myenv python=3.6`, you can select all available Python versions from the Navigator as well, e.g. Python 3.5.